# Onclick function not work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, undefined, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to add a submit function in my HTML and refer to a js file with my function. The code runs successfully in Chrome but not in IE11. The error message is "submitFunc(event) is undefined". Could anyone help me fix this problem? I have tried everything I can. T.T

```js
function submitFunc(event) {
        console.log("Hey what are you looking for? ") 
    }
```

```html
<html>
<div>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitFunc(event)">
</div>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: your posted code works identically in firefox, chrome, edge **and** IE11 - however, if you are loading the page using `file:///` protocol, then you may well have issues with internet exploder

Comment: Do you mean I should change src="/static/js/main.js" to other calling method? @JaromandaX . Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No. I said the code you posted works ok in all browsers. Something else is wrong. Check the browser developer tools console for other errors when loading the page for example

Comment: Yes, you are right! I found the problem which is that IE doesn't support  function Object.values(). So after I change it, it works well.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your `<script>` tag in outside of the `<html>...</html>` block. Try moving it up into the a `<head>...</head>` section just after the first `<html>` tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping! @kshetline I tried to put the <script> tag as you mentioned but the same error still occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help, but you're loading the JavaScript file after setting up the on-click event. I would assume that means you don't have the function defined yet. I would move the "script" tag before the elements.

Comment: maybe you could explain more, but for good old IE this did fix it for me :)   Other browsers aren't so picky after everything is loaded once.